# How do I create multidimensional arrays in java which store ints and strings?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, oracle, multidimensional-array

I have got the data created in SQL which stores details about a car dealership. I just dont know how to store data from sql in java which i can then write methods for such as totaal sales in 2009. I have querys written in sql which i want to test to see if the results as the same.

Any ideas as to how I would store details for say a Vechicle table. Would hold vehicle id, make, model, price etc.

Thanks

Comment: Vehicle class - what java was made for. You can then have a collection (dealers choice) of Vehicles.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java, in it's Object Orientation glory, let's you represent your "Vehicle" object just as you need it. You can create a class named **Vehicle** that has private variables to hold the data of your columns.

You can then add methods to get/set said variables and treat your Vehicle as a whole.

Last, you can manage a set of Vehicle(**s**) as a collection.

A real quick look would be as such:

```
public class Vehicle {
   private int id;
   private String make;
   private String model;

   public Vehicle(){}

   public Vehicle(int id, String make, String model){
       this.id=id;
       this.make=make;
       this.model=model;
   }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }
    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.model + " " + this.make + " " + this.id;
    }

}
```

You can take this even further. If you notice that the private variables have many things in common and you use them as a whole rather than separately, then you can create another class that englobes those private variables.

The possibilities are endless.

Then the class that carries out the sql queries can also handle returning a collection of Vehicles.

```
 ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

//This is just for show, here you would iterate through the data/cursor/etc
// that you get back from the sql query
for(Row row: rows) {
   vehicles.add(new Vehicle(Integer.parseInt(row.getColumn("id")),
                            row.getColumn("make").toString(),
                            row.getColumn("model").toString()
               );
}
 return vehicles;
```

Then to see if it works just iterate over your collections and print it out.

```
for(Vehicle vehicle:vehicles)
    System.out.println(vehicle);
```

You can do the `System.out.println(vehicle)` call thanks to the fact that the class Vehicle overrides the method `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Vehicle object and fill it with the relevant data as follows:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    private int id;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private double price;

    public Vehicle(int id, String make, String model, double price)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMake()
    {
        return make;
    }
    public void setMake(String make)
    {
        this.make = make;
    }
    public String getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have information from 5 different tables all relating to different topics such as time and branch. Is there anyway of storing information regarding all of these tables in one class? I have to use multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: You could create a class that represents the dealership. This class could contain a list of Vehicles and other class you have.

Answer (score 0):

A very minor suggestion:
change this:
  ArrayList < Vehicle > vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
to this:
  List < Vehicle > vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
in the previous post.